# Calling a Batch File in Python Does Not Properly Execute

Tags: windows, python-3.x, batch-file, cmd, pycharm

This is my first post, and I am very green with coding in Python.
My intent is to call a batch file to execute from within a Python script.

I have done my due diligence with research, and discovered the
call() method with the library: (from subprocess import call), and the
os.system() method with the library: (import os)

Here are some details:

1. When I run the batch script manually, it executes each line of code as expected.

2. When I call the batch script from Python with either of the two above methods, part of the batch file executes.

Here is the code in the batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "test" >> file.txt
PAUSE
```

Here is the code for the Python script using the os.system() method

```
import os

runfile = "C:\\Data\\Automation\\Test\\run.bat"
os.system(runfile)
print("Hello World")
```

Now when I run the batch script manually, a file is written to my drive as (file.txt) as expected.

But when I run the Python script, all of the code in the batch file is executed, except for the "ECHO "test" >> file.txt"

And what is really interesting is within PyCharm the Batch File output is appearing in my status window! Its like the code within the batch file somehow integrates inside of Python. And it does not only appear, but it is also possible to interact with it!

So here is all the steps:

1. Run the Python Script

2. Call BatchScript

3. PROBLEM: The file.txt is not being written to disk

4. Output 'Press any key to continue . . ." within the Python status window

5. Press Enter

(Return to finish executing the rest of the Python code)

6. Output "Hello World" within the Python status window

As you can see the issue is:
Manual execution of the batch script causes the file.txt to be written
where Execution of the python script does not write the file.txt to disk

I hope this is some solid detail to help pin point what the issue might be.

Thank you so very much for helping out with this, all of your time and efforts are greatly appreciated!!! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wonder what your current working directory actually is at the time the Python script starts the .bat script. Specify that the `file.txt` should be created in the same directory as the .bat file script, or specify the full path to another directory.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "test" >>"%~dp0file.txt"
PAUSE
```

or

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "test" >>"%USERPROFILE%\file.txt"
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this, everything works perfectly! :)